# S3 and CloudFront website hosting for multiple SPA redirect to different index.html based by url path

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, single-page-application, amazon-cloudfront

I have a single S3 bucket for multiple Single Page Applications, and enabled static website hosting for this bucket. Bucket has the following folders and files (firstApp & secondApp are folders and correspond to different SPA):

```
firstApp
    index.html
    *.js & *.css files
secondApp
    index.html
    *.js & *.css files
```

Also I setup CloudFront in front of S3 bucket, default root object is set to `index.html`.
And now `cloud-front-url/firstApp/` displays `index.html` from firstApp SPA and `cloud-front-url/secondApp` displays `index.html` from secondApp.

I need that all incorrect requests redirect to different `index.html` for specific app based by url path, e.g. if someone requests `cloud-front-url/firstApp/non-existing-path` - it should redirect to `index.html` from firstApp and similar behavior for secondApp.

I know how to setup CloudFront to redirect all 404 errors to a single `index.html`:

```
select distribution > Error Pages > Create custom error response:
* Http error code: 404
* Error Caching Minimum TTL (seconds) : 0
* Customize response: Yes
* Response Page Path : /firstApp/index.html
* HTTP Response Code: 200
```

Is it possible with CloudFront to redirect 404 errors to different `index.html` based on requested path (redirect to `index.html` either in firstApp or secondApp folder)?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at S3 Routing Rules. These can catch requests that return 404 not found and redirect the user to a specific url. I'm not sure if it handles subdirectories but it's worth a gander.

Comment: @TomNijs, thanks for your suggestion. I already take a look at S3 Routing Rules. Seems they have possibility to handle subpaths with `<KeyPrefixEquals>`, but I need another behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When hosting a static website on S3, it's not possible to have different 404 pages. Generally speaking, one bucket has one 404 error page.

You could host your two applications in two separate buckets. Each would have it's own 404 error page.

Then, in CloudFront, use multiple behaviours pointing to each separate bucket. This way, `/firstApp/` goes to bucket1, and `/secondApp/` goes to bucket2.

Comment: Or just two (sub)domains, two distributions, two buckets.  No difference in cost, either way.

Comment: Thanks for the options. My 2c: while there is no difference in cost there is a difference in operations and maintaining multiple 'stuff'. Consider 1 bucket /app * 6 apps * 2 environments => a lot of stuff to manage, track, etc

Comment: @ieugen I would argue the opposite: multi-purposing resources increases complexity. By keeping resources seperated and single-purpose, things are easier to build and manage, especially when you are using CloudFormation and similar tools. Environments can be duplicated and updated much easier.

Comment: @MattHouser: you actually have a good point. I've ran into the issue systems like swis army knifes and they create pain to deal with, especially over time. 
I guess doing things the right way, the first time requires investment. Thanks.

Comment: So I'm trying to do the same thing but always getting AccessDenied on my apps, how exactly did you configure the behaviors?